# How to parse xml api in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am very new to Xamarin and developing a cross platform application. So can anyone here help me guiding how to parse the xml api that I can use in the shared code also. It will be very helpful if anyone can provide me with the link or the demo of same thing.

Comment: Your question is very vague.  Are you trying to parse XML data returned by a webservice call?  If so, you use the normal C# XML mechanisms - either XDocument or XMLDocument.

Comment: Yes I am trying to parse the xml data returned by web service call, do you have link or tutorial that can help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Xml.Serialization. It helps serialize objects into XML format and deserialize of an XML file back to an object.

[See more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)